# How to use CKEditor 5 Image upload?

Tags: vb.net, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Hi I am currently using CKEditor 5 and my problem is the image upload. The ckeditor allows me to upload an image and it displays within the CKEditor, the file is also being uploaded to a folder using a custom VB Script but i keep getting the error: Cannot upload file - filename. Then the Image disappears from ckeditor. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? is the image URL not being passed back properly to CKEditor?

```js
    var myEditor;
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#CKEditor1'), {

            ckfinder: {
                filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form',
                // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
                uploadUrl: 'Scripts/uploadVB.aspx?CKEditor=CKEditor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en'
            }
        })
        .then(editor => {
            console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
            myEditor = editor;
            
        })
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
        });
```

```html
 <div id="CKEditor1">This is some sample content.</div>
```

```html
UploadVB Page

<%@ Page Language="VB" Strict="true"%>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/22.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script runat="server">
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Response.Write(processUpload())
        'processUpload()
    End Sub
    'https://github.com/AlfonsoML/CKEditorUploader/blob/master/uploadVB.aspx
   
       
        Dim basePath As String = "C:\Users\new\Image\CN_Image"
        ' Step 3: Put here the Url that should be used for the upload folder (it the URL to access the folder that you have set in $basePath
        ' you can use a relative url "/images/", or a path including the host "http://example.com/images/"
        ' ALWAYS put the final slash (/)
        Dim baseUrl As String = "/Image/CN_Image/"
        ' Done. Now test it!
        ' No need to modify anything below this line
        '----------------------------------------------------
        ' ------------------------
        ' Input parameters: optional means that you can ignore it, and required means that you
        ' must use it to provide the data back to CKEditor.
        ' ------------------------
        ' Optional: instance name (might be used to adjust the server folders for example)


        Dim CKEditor As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("CKEditor")

        ' Required: Function number as indicated by CKEditor.
        Dim funcNum As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("CKEditorFuncNum")
        'Dim CKEditorFuncNum As String = Context.Request("CKEditorFuncNum")
        ' Optional: To provide localized messages
        Dim langCode As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("langCode")
        ' ------------------------
        ' Data processing
        ' ------------------------
        Dim total As Integer
        Try
            total = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return sendError("Error uploading the file")
        End Try
        If (total = 0) Then
            Return sendError("No file has been sent")
        End If
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(basePath)) Then
            Return sendError("basePath folder doesn't exists")
        End If
        'Grab the file name from its fully qualified path at client
        Dim theFile As HttpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files(0)
        Dim strFileName As String = theFile.FileName
        If (strFileName = "") Then
            Return sendError("File name is empty")
        End If
        Dim sFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName)
        Dim name As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, sFileName)
        theFile.SaveAs(name)
        Dim url As String = baseUrl + sFileName.Replace("'", "\'")

        ' ------------------------
        ' Write output
        ' ------------------------

        Return "<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript'> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + funcNum + ", '" + url + "', '')</scr" + "ipt>"


    End Function
    Private Function sendError(ByVal msg As String) As String
        Dim funcNum As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("CKEditorFuncNum")
        Return "<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript'> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + funcNum + ", '', '" + msg + "')</scr" + "ipt>"
    End Function
</script>
```

Comment: What enviroment are you running this in?  IIS?  Does you application pool have the required permissions to access the location you're attempting to save the file too?

Comment: Its just from visual basic localhost, yes it has permissions to save to a folder